# How to write XPATH for the below span class in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How to write XPATH for the below span class element in Selenium?

```
<span class ="menu-item-text">
<span class ="menu-text">Selenium</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the text "Selenium" by using the xpath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='menu-text']"));
String elementText = element.getText();
```

However, you can also fetch the text by using the classname in this case like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("menu-text"));
String elementText = element.getText();
```

Comment: I am trying to automate ToolTip in Selenium through the website - https://demo.stqatools.com/ToolTip.php.
Could you please help me to get the xpath for the below snippet of code?

    <div>
    <span tooltip="I'm up above it!">Up</span>
    </div>

thanks in advance

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi for the tooltip, you can find the element by using the xpath `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Up']"))` Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hello Sameer.. the xpath didnt work. I got Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[text()='Up']"}. I tried using the below xpath and it worked- //html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/span.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='Up']"))`  is the correct xpath.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Up']"))` should also work. @ChaitanyaMaligi please dont use the xpath that you are using now as that might not work in future if any changes happen in the div structure. Please use the one i have mentioned just now or the one that Supputuri has mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @SameerArora .Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Thank you @supputuri .Appreciate your help on this.